# flask how to log all warning exceptions (full stack trace) to file

Tags: python, apache, logging, flask, flask-restful

So I am trying to build a restful API using flask, served up by apache on centos (httpd).

Basic API calls work just fine but I am not making much progress on the more advanced aspects because every time it fails I just get an HTTP 500 response which is completely useless for troubleshooting and I have no server-side logs to look at. I am literally trying to solve this through trial and error and it is making me bang my head against the wall.

In order to make any progress on this project I need to setup some basic error logging, but I do not understand the documentation or existing threads about this. It is completely over my head.

What I want to do is have flask write out all warnings and exceptions generated by my application to a specific file (it can be in the app directory to keep it simple).

I am looking for the simplest, easiest, least mind bendy way of doing this... suggestions?

Here is a very simplified version of my app... it shows the basic structure I am using, so please use that for reference.

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
    from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Resource, Api

    app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(app)

    class fetchTicket(Resource):
        def post(self):

        request_data = request.get_json(force=True)

        r_ticket_id = request_data['ticket_id']

        return jsonify(ticket_id=r_ticket_id)


    api.add_resource(fetchTicket, '/ticket/fetch')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import logging
        from logging.handlers import FileHandler

        app.debug = True
        file_handler = FileHandler("/var/www/project_folder/error.log")
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        app.run()
```

But when I run the above code no error.log file is created. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Note: I did set the folder permissions so that the apache user has access to write to the directory where the log file should go, as per http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache but it did not help so I don't think it is a permissions issue.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/errorhandling/, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#debug-mode

Comment: second link is only relevant to the flask dev server no? I am using apache.

Comment: I added some test code to the original question that I made based off the first link that Celeo posted. But my code does not create the log file, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to explicitly include the stack trace when logging, using the extra kwarg.

```
logger.exception('Probably something went wrong', extra={'stack': True})
```